# Drawing a image at an angle in android

Tags: android, image, angle, android-canvas

I needed to draw an image at an angle, for on of my project.

I am aware about the canvas.rotate() code. However it does distort my image.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(30);
ctx.drawImage();
ctx.restore();
```

Is there any other way to draw an image at an angle. Did any one else come across the problem of distortion while drawing images using the above technique?

BR,
Jayshil

Comment: What exactly do you mean by distortion? If you rotate an image, it may be clipped since the rotated image has different dimensions than the initial image... is that what happened, or is it blurred or something?

Comment: @aleph_null Its not getting clipped. The shape of the image is getting distorted for example if its a cupboard image which i am tilting, the edges lose the sharpness and becomes rippled. I hope i am clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found the answer,

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
matrix.postRotate(-25);
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(productImage, 0, 0, productImage.getWidth(), productImage.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

This solution was inspired by http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html solution give by Maurl